# Good algorithm to use for classifying keywords

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, python

I have looked at the suggested posts but none addresses this specific problem

I have groups of keywords which describe textual resources derived using word2vec

I would like to train a supervised algorithm to relate groups of five or six keywords (as tokens) to one of several predefined categories

ie.

warm, hot, sunny, bucket, sea || beach

work, laptop, meeting, desk || office

etc

I have used and deployed a working LSTM model with tensorflow/keras which I could adapt to use a softmax classification output but as i dont need memory in any sense, the positional relationship of the tokenised keywords is irrelevant, and due to the simplicity of the problem it seems like overkill for an RNN and maybe even a neural network altogether

Does anyone have a suggestion of a lightweight cheap (computationally) model that would be best suited for this

I like the idea of using softmax to predict probability of each category as we may ultimately classify a list of keywords in more than one category using the probability as a threshold.

Can be in either R or Python, i added tensorflow as a tag as there may be a good tensorflow solution, but this is not important, could be an R algorithm or SciKit Learn etc

Thanks for your advice!

Danny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your problem you can use LDA (Latent Dirichlet Allocation), "which is a commonly used 
method for feature selection, which reduces the dimensionality in the data by discovering latent topics to explain documents in the text (Blei, 2003). This method is in the category of probabilistic topic models.

The goal of this type of models is to infer the structure of the hidden topics based on the observed documents. In more technical terms, a joint distribution is used to calculate the conditional distribution of the hidden variables given the observed documents i.e. the posterior distribution." -- This is from a small report that friends and I wrote on "Topic Modelling" within documents.

With other words, LDA will give you a number (you have to choose it using different techniques) of topics (eg. beach, office..) and the words that fall within each topic.

In R you can use:

1) FindTopicsNumber from ldatuning to find the optimal number of topics.

2) LDA from topicmodels to identify the topics.

3) You can then join each word to the given topic using a gamma distribution.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: you absolute LEGEND! thanks so much. What a wonderful introduction to this part of Stack : )

Comment: Just a note, the topics are "factors" so they will come unnamed. However, you having the words under each topic will give you the ability to name the topics yourself.

For example: warm, hot, sunny, bucket, sea || Topic 1. Then you can identify topic 1 as "Beach".

Moreover, you will have the probability of observing a specific term in a topic. Eg.: Sunny has 88% probability of occuring in Topic 1 (beach) and 0.3% probability of occuring in Topic 2 (office).